# Can't send email to custom domain

Tags: php, email, sender, phishing

I have an issue where I can't receive email at certain domains. I believe it's most likely down to spam detection so I have checked headers are set correctly. However I'm still not receiving the emails at certain domains.

Example:

Let's say my sending domain is: `diggersworld.com`.

My PHP is setup like so:

```
// general data
$recipient = '...';
$subject = '...';
$message = '...';

// set headers
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Diggersworld <info@diggersworld.com>";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

// send email
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers))) {
    ...
}
```

I can receive the emails with Hotmail, I'm guessing their spam scanning is more relaxed. But when sending to a custom domain it's not getting there.

I've tried sending a bare bones `mail()` with no headers. Again it made it to Hotmail, but not a custom domain.

Comment: I would probably contact `1and1 hosting` and get some mail logs to see why it's being rejected. It could be that you've tried to send mail to that address over and over and they're deferred your ability to send any more mail. It could be that you need to send other headers to verify you're not just spamming their server, it could be a host of things, but alas, you should see if you can get logs from them.

Comment: You said you received on hotmail.. in other domains, did you checked the spam box/trash ?

Comment: @rennyrocha I did and they were empty too.

Comment: Try using PHPMailer or SwiftMailer classes...